# Dealing with a broken toilet flange on PVC pipe

Tags: plumbing, toilet, pvc, flange

So I'm about to tile my bathroom floor but the toilet flange broke and can't get it out I tried with a chisel and hammer but I think I got the pipe to so how can I fix this situation I got here[image]

Comment: "I think I got the pipe to"  Are you certain you cracked the pipe below?

Comment: Not sure if I did or not I don't think I did

Comment: I'm going to say yes

Comment: So expose the pipe properly and replace the damaged section.

Comment: By exposing the pipe you mean cut some of the cement around it?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the pipe below the concrete is OK, you can buy a [replacement flange](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-4-in-PVC-DWV-Replacement-Closet-Flange-43539/100139480) that is designed to sit inside the pipe and grip the pipe in such as way as to secure the toilet

[image]

If the pipe below the concrete is damaged, you'll need to excavate the concrete and replace the entire damaged section. The good news there is you can install a new flange directly connected to the pipe then.